# Recording multiple videos at once using AVFoundation / QTKit

Tags: avfoundation, qtkit

Using AVFoundation/QTKit how would you record multiple video devices at same time to a file/files?

I know how to record them separately but trying to record both at once causes errors like...

"cannot be added to the session because the source and destination media types are incompatible."

Thanks in advance

Comment: FWIW I'm not sure that you can write to the same file from two output devices at once. Even if you could it would be a mess. They will have to record in separate files. On that note, are you trying to record both front and back camera at the same time?

Comment: Currently I'm trying to record desktop and a webcam at same time. Sort of how screenflow does it (and they do it to one file). Im guessing they somehow attach the inputs to a custom output data writer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an article explaining how you can do it:

[Capturing from multiple devices with QTKit](http://www.subfurther.com/blog/2007/12/04/capturing-from-multiple-devices-with-qtkit/)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, we would like you to include the essential parts of the linked article in your answer, and provide the [link for reference](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259). Failing to do that leaves the answer at risk from link rot.

Comment: Unfortunately the example is based around viewing the multiple devices rather than recording to a actual file/files which is part of my requirement.